# Get Current User info using wp_localize_script, in functions.php

Tags: functions, javascript, users, wp-localize-script

I need to pass the info from `wp_get_current_user()` to the front end for a script that uses it. To achieve this, I am using `wp_localize_script()` to pass the information. I put the code at the top of my `functions.php` file but it doesn't work.

Here it is. The idea is that on the login event, the `add_to_login()` function is triggered, whose job it is to add a function to the `wp_enqueue_scripts`, called `add_to_enqueue()`. Finally, in `add_to_enqueue()`, I pass the info to the localized script. I already tried this only using `wp_enqeue_scripts` so without using `wp_login` in addition. It seemed the problem was that current user is not available for retrieval until after `wp_enqueue_scripts` occurs.

```
function add_to_enqueue() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $dataToBePassed = array(
       'userId' => $current_user['user_login'],
       'userName' => $current_user['display_name'],
    );
    wp_register_script('getUserInfo', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/getUserInfo.js');

    wp_localize_script('getUserInfo', 'php_vars', $dataToBePassed);
    wp_enqueue_script('getUserInfo'); 
}

function add_to_login() {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_to_enqueue');
    do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts'); 
} 
add_action('wp_login', 'add_to_login');
```

Comment: What purpose is served by attaching the script to login rather than just deriving the values directly (on init)? Logging in already changes those values, which would be available to wp_localize_script().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hook_javascript() {

    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        $output="<script> var userObject = ".json_encode(wp_get_current_user())."; console.log(JSON.stringify(userObject)); </script>";
        echo $output;
    } else {
        $output="<script> var userObject; </script>";
        echo $output;
    }
}
add_action('wp_head','hook_javascript');
```

Comment: Does this still work in WP?  Im getting undefined in the console log

Answer (score 1):

If you read about this action [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login).

You will see that this hook provides access to two parameters, `$user->user_login (string)` and `$user ( WP_User` ).

Using it like this you will see all the info you have access to:

```
function add_to_login($user_login, $user)
{
    echo "<pre>".print_r($user, true)."</pre>";
}
add_action('wp_login', 'add_to_login', 10, 2);
```

But after a little testing I don't see how you can use this info with your JS as the user is immediately redirected after this action. Your script won't have time to do anything.

Comment: Your method of getting the user is certainly far easier thanks for pointing that out. Ultimately I found that since the wp_enqueue_scripts hook happens before the wp_login hook, I couldn't tie the info gotten from the login to to enqueue my script. Instead, i inject the info into the header of every page using the wp_head hook which is when any page gets the <head></head> section. This works beautifully, here is the code.

Comment: `function hook_javascript() {
    
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        $output="<script> var userObject = ".json_encode(wp_get_current_user())."; console.log(JSON.stringify(userObject)); </script>";
        echo $output;
    } else {
        $output="<script> var userObject; </script>";
        echo $output;
    }
}
add_action('wp_head','hook_javascript');`